# Solving the "Library of Babel" puzzle, but for polygons.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, polygons, combinations

[The Library of Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Library_of_Babel) is a story about a universe whose contents are every possible 410-page book that could possibly exist. After a conversation with someone about doing this with images, and coming to the conclusion that even the smallest constraints produce infeasible results (e.g. a 2x2 pixel RGB image has 4,195,020,000 possibilities) I moved on to thinking about polygons instead.

The more I thought about it, the more complex the maths became to me. Let's assume we've got a grid of $x$ by $y$ points, so the total number of points on the grid is $p = xy$. Let's also assume that each polygon can be one of $c$ different colours. If we assume that the corners of each polygon must occupy three distinct points on that grid, how would we go about calculating the number of possible images? Note that two *different* polygons may use the same points, but one individual polygon must not use the same point twice.

My first thought is that for one polygon, it's a case of computing combinations, and then permutations based on colour. But when we add more polygons, I get confused.

How would I go about calculating this?

Comment: You should be more precise about degeneracy. Can a triangle be
constructed with three points that are aligned. Can a vertex of a
polygon sit on an edge between two other vertices. Can an edge sit on
another edge with different ending vertices. These choices are
as arbitrary as forbidding to use twice the same vertex, as it could
be for two different pairs of edges. Also, I do not understand what is
special about these three points. Are they chosen points that are to
be common vertices to all acceptable polygons, or is it that each
polygon has three unshared points? What are the colors for?

Comment: Very good point, I hadn't considered the problem of three points on the same line. That should certainly be disallowed. On the other hand, yes, two different polygons can share edges. The points are "randomly" chosen - the polygons may overlap, or share edges, share a single point, or they may be completely separate. The colours are an extension of the original idea of generating all possible images that could exist.

Comment: Do we have a solution for the number of non degenerate triangles in a pxq lattice?

Comment: I think disallowing degeneracy makes the problem a lot more complex,
as you have to identify all possible alignments of points. Also you
did not clarify the emaning of "_we assume that the corners of each
polygon must occupy three distinct points on that grid_". Disallowing
the same point twice simplifies the problem, but disallow perfectly
valid polygons (though with ambiguous side order). You do not say how
many polygons make an image. I still think the problem very
unprecise. I am not sure how it can be made precise and interesting.

Comment: The number of polygons is arbitrary - one would include variable that as part of the solution. I also don't see how a polygon that has, essentially, two distinct points is valid - it's an infinitesimally thin line.